# abd is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: android, selenium, appium, windows-nt

I am trying to install appium in windows OS. I added tools and platform-tools folder path into the system path. But still adb is not recognizable by the system!!!!

**CMD Output Image** :
[image: Console Output]

**Folder View** :

[image: Folder View]

Comment: I added images for better understanding.

Comment: I added images for better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You have a space in your path after "platform-tools".